# Как растянуть фон на сайт в портретной ориентации с помощью css?

Tags: css, background

Писал сайт и у меня возникла проблема в портретной ориентации фотография на фоне (завёрнутая в div) растягивалась некорректно даже при заданных width и height 100%

Comment: Немного кода не повредит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size: cover;` - Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы его ширина или высота равнялась ширине или высоте блока.
или
`background-size:contain;` -Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций таким образом, чтобы картинка целиком поместилась внутрь блока.